# Python Dropbox API - Invalid "cursor" parameter

Tags: python, dropbox-api

I've been migrating some Python 2.7.11 code to 3.5.1 after running into trouble with unicode. This was the last straw - since I started using the venv module there's no reason to be on 2.7 just because someone doesn't like 3!

The problem occurs while trying to run a one-way sync (ie. downloading changes only).

Here is the full error message, paths shortened:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "%SCRIPT%.py", line 209, in <module>
    updated_schedules = dbx_sync.One_Way_Sync(config['Dropbox Parameters']['Directory'], config['Dropbox Parameters']['Base Path'])
  File "%COMMON_PATH%\modules\dropbox_sync_schedules.py", line 62, in One_Way_Sync
    result = client.delta(cursor, base_path)
  File "%COMMON_PATH%\env-home\lib\site-packages\dropbox\client.py", line 569, in delta
    return self.rest_client.POST(url, params, headers)
  File "%COMMON_PATH%\env-home\lib\site-packages\dropbox\rest.py", line 322, in POST
    return cls.IMPL.POST(*n, **kw)
  File "%COMMON_PATH%\env-home\lib\site-packages\dropbox\rest.py", line 260, in POST
    is_json_request=is_json_request)
  File "%COMMON_PATH%\env-home\lib\site-packages\dropbox\rest.py", line 235, in request
    raise ErrorResponse(r, r.read())
dropbox.rest.ErrorResponse: [400] 'Invalid "cursor" parameter: u"b\'\'"'
```

Searching for "invalid cursor parameter" wasn't any help, so I thought I'd come here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`u"b\'\'"` is the key here. I just couldn't understand how that representation had ended up being sent as a string.

The issue was in reading the old cursor from a file (which for this example is empty): in Python 2 I had opened the file in mode `rb` - in Python 3 just `r` is all that's required, and everything works.

Hurrah!